# Wordpress 4.8.2 REST API could not delete a post

Tags: wordpress, rest

I am trying to delete a post using Wordpress 4.8.2 REST API by sending 
DELETE to URL like http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/4
I have WP Basic Auth plugin installed and activated.
I am sending 'Authorization' header = 'Basic base64 encoding of (username:password)'
However as an API response I get

```
 {
        "code": "rest_cannot_delete",
        "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to delete this post.",
        "data": {
            "status": 401
        }
    }
```

Could you please inform why it's not deleting the post? Thanks

Comment: the same URL works on reading with GET ?

Comment: Hi mmm, yes it works for GET and I am able to get a list of posts.

Comment: can the user delete the post when he is connected in the WordPress backend ?

Comment: yes he is able to delete from WP backend